# Writing a for loop in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics

I don't know how to write for-loops in r. Here is what I want to do:

I have a df called "na" with 50 columns `(ana1_1:ana50_1)`. I want to loop these commands over all columns. Here are the commands for the first two columns (`ana1_1` and `ana2_1`):

```
t<-table(na$ana1_1)
ana1_1<-capture.output(sort(t))    
cat(ana1_1,file="ana.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE)     
t<-table(na$ana2_1) 
ana2_1<-capture.output(sort(t)) 
cat(ana2_1,file="ana.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE)
```

After the loop, all tables `(ana1_1:ana50_1)` should be written in ana.txt Has anyone an idea, how to solve the problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(na, function(x) {x1 <- capture.output(sort(table(x)));cat(x1, file='ana.txt', sep="\n", append=TRUE)})`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to loop through the columns with `lapply` and using the same code as in the OP's post

```
 invisible(lapply(na, function(x) {
               x1 <- capture.output(sort(table(x)))
               cat(x1, file='ana.txt', sep="\n", append=TRUE)
  }))
```

Wrapping with `invisible` so that it won't print 'NULL' in the R console.

We can wrap with a condition to check if the file already exists so that it won't add the same lines by accidentally running the code again.

```
if(!file.exists('ana.txt')){
   invisible( lapply(na, function(x) {
        x1 <- capture.output(sort(table(x)))
        cat(x1, file='ana.txt', sep="\n", append=TRUE)
   }))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a `for` loop. Loops tend to be slow in r so people prefer other solutions (e.g. the great answer provided by akrun). This answer is for your understanding of the loop syntax:

```
for(i in 1:50){
  t1<-table(na[,i])
  t2<-capture.output(sort(t1))    
  cat(t2,file="ana.txt",sep="\n",append=TRUE) 
}
```

We are looping through `i` from 1 to 50 (first line). To select a column there's two (there's actually more than two, but that's for another time) ways to access it: `na$ana1_1` or `na[,1]` both select the first column (second line). In the first case you refer by column name, in the second by column index. Here the second case is more convenient. The rest is your desired calculations.

Be aware that `cat` creates a new file if `ana.txt` is not existing yet and appends to it if it is already there.

Comment: this is a fine answer, technically, but note that `for` loops in R are *not* typically slower than their `*apply()` counterparts; see [chapter 4 of Burns's R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for pointing out. I'm aware of that chapter and I was trying to allude to this with "tend to" in my answer. Given that it is a didactic answer I'd leave it as it is, however you are completely right and especially in this case the `lapply` is just a hidden loop as akrun is also mentioning.